# Why is std::equal_to useful?

Tags: c++, c++11

The C++ standard library provides [`std::equal_to`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/equal_to). This function object invokes `operator==` on type `T` by default.

What's the benefit of using `std::equal_to`? Could you provide an example where `std::equal_to` is useful?

Comment: You cannot pass `==` to a function, but you can pass `std::equal_to`.

Comment: It's a bit historical, as you can also pass `[ ](auto a, auto b) { return a==b; }`

Comment: @MSalters: Isn't std::equal_to template-defined to be exactly that? Or at least, `[ ](const T& a, const U& b) { return a==b; }` ?

Comment: @einpoklum: No, can't, since a lambda is an object and `std::equal_to` is a type.

Comment: Allows you to define an `equals_to` specialisation where a given type does not provide an overload for `==`.  Alternatively, if you need to define equality in a non-standard fashion for a particular algorithm.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

To be used in algorithms. It provides a functor with operator() on it, and thus can be used generically.

Specific (and contrived) example, as asked in comments:

```
// compare two sequences and produce a third one
// having true for positions where both sequences
// have equal elements
std::transform(seq1.begin(), seq1.end(), seq2.begin(), 
               std::inserter(resul), std::equal_to<>());
```

Not sure who might need it, but it is an example.

Comment: It would be great, if you could give a concrete code example (and mention, why `operator==` cannot be used directly for some cases). Unfortunately the reference documentation link I added to the post is missing a concise example yet.

Comment: @SergeyA `std::equal_to` is a class template, you either specify a type template argument, `std::equal_to<int>()`, or (in C++14), you use its transparent (diamond) version `std::equal_to<>()`

Comment: @SergeyA The most complete answer. I also agree with @Lightness Races in Orbit - `equal_to` is a little bit redundant because of the lambda functions, but the readability is much better.

Answer (score 23):

Having `std::equal_to` is very useful because it allows the equality comparison to be used as a functor, which means that it can be passed as an argument to templates and functions. This is something that isn't possible with the equality operator `==` since operators simply cannot be passed as parameters.

Consider, for example, how it can be used with [`std::inner_product`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inner_product),  [`std::find_first_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find_first_of) and [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map).

Answer (score 9):

These days, it's not really. Before lambdas it was useful as a functor form of a call to `==`, for use in standard algorithm calls. Nowadays you'd just write `[](auto& x, auto& y) { return x == y; }`.

Comment: I would still prefer equal_to to the above notation. Much shorter, quicker grasp time.

Comment: @SergeyA Shorter, yes. Quicker to grasp, doubtful.

Comment: @Barry, subjectional, of course. But lambda requires someone to actually read the lambda, and make sure it does nothing fancy. equal_to is straight as an arrow.

Comment: _@Lightness Races in Orbit_ `equal_to()` obviously is shorter and implies semantical clearness over a lambda, you have to decipher. Giving things names, makes the intention clearer.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? If there's already an `equal_to` function object, why would you write a lambda?

Comment: I dunno; I guess my point is more that `std::equal_to` is not useful enough to add it now if it didn't already exist. It doesn't meet the threshold for inclusion in the standard, given what else has since been added. In that sense, it's not "useful". But sure there are times you may want to make use of it.

Comment: Don't you mean `const auto&`s in your lambda?

Comment: @einpoklum: This was already covered in comments above ... which have for some reason been deleted. :(

Comment: Assuming that `==` is defined for the type in question.

Comment: @simon.watts Of course, to compare two objects of a type for equality, an equality relation must be defined for those types in the usual way.

Answer (score 9):

It's intended primarily to be passed as a template parameter to an algorithm. You can't specify an operator as a template parameter, but you can specify a function. Typical use would be something like:

```
template <class compare = std::equal_to<>, class T, class InIter>
bool contains(InIter begin, InIter end, T value, compare cmp={}) {
  for (InIter p = begin; p != end; ++p)
    if (cmp(*p, value))
      return true;
  return false;
}
```

If you have (for example) a structure of some sort that contains several fields, you might want a comparison function that only compares a few specific fields that indicate the identity, such as a person's name, but ignoring other fields such as their current weight, pay grade, etc. In such a case, you'd pass that comparison function as a template parameter, and be able to compare only the fields you care about.

For other cases where you're dealing with, say, searching an array of integers, you can use the default comparison function.

Comment: you don't instantiate `cmp`

Comment: at one of the places that i worked, one of the coding guidelines is/was "always have the constant on left side of operator == "...so, i guess,  std::equal_to also avoids that

Comment: also, default type template parameters for functions did not exist before C++11, and putting one as the last parameter won't let anyone to specify it explicitly without the preceding ones (inhibiting type deduction)

Comment: Making `cmp` as the last type argument seems silly, as it makes it nearly unusable with anything except the default.  I'd add another arg, `cmp c={}`, and then use `c(p,value)` within the function.  And I'd probably make `cmp` the first type argument to the `contains` template function.

Comment: @basav: That is/was a guideline from the last century, when compilers did not warn you for something like `if (x = 5)`. Or perhaps it was a solution in search of a problem even back then; I'm too young to really know.

Comment: @Christian: say the developer ignores/fails to notice warning and the code could exist in a path that does not get exercised during test run , so the developer happily pushes it to repository :) trust me , i have seen it happen and it's notoriously hard to detect in such cases

Comment: @Yakk: Good point--edited accordingly (not that the intent was really to create a particularly usable function, just to show the general kind of situation where you might use `std::equal_to` (or similar, such as `std::less`, std::greater`, etc.)

Comment: @basav: Sounds like a buggy development process: ignoring warnings + no code reviews.

Comment: @basav, warnings as errors are you friends. Suppress order of initialization warning, of course.

Comment: @Christian: ridiculous timelines and stressed out team....and domain was medical imaging :) that's how bad it was.

Comment: @SergeyA: Why would you suppress that?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, never in my life I have seen to be of any value. I have seen it a lot breaking builds (in warnings as errors mode) when dealing with external, non-editable header files, which had order of initialization 'incorrect'. While you can construct an example where order of initialization would matter, I have never seen it. And I believe any design which would be broken by this is overengineered.

Comment: @SergeyA: I've seen it a few times. Just write the initialisers in the proper order. How hard can that really be? (And if you have errors-as-warnings enabled on third-party library code, you are doing something wrong.)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, wat? I am talking about external libraries headers included in my files. How on earth would you selectively disable warnings in this case???

Comment: @SergeyA: Um, GCC already does by default....... https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-Headers.html